# Why 2^(2n+2) not equal to θ(2^2n)?

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I'm trying to prove this expression 2^(2n+2) ≠ θ(2^2n)?
Firstly 0 <= c1.2^(2n) <= 2^(2n+2) for this n=1 c1=1 is a solution set.
For n = ∞, 0 <= ∞.c1 <= ∞ c1=1 is provide it. So omega notation part is okay.
Second part is Big O notation so it should be 2^(2n+2) <= c2.2^2n.
For n=1 it's 8 <= 4c2, c2 can be 3.
For n=∞, it's ∞ <= c2.∞, c2=1 is provide it.
Why it's not equal? Can anybody explain? I can see the f(n)'s degree bigger than g(n)'s. So it should be only 2^(2n+2)= Ω(2^2n). But I couldn't show it with sample solution sets. Cause my solution sets equations seem to be correct. Can anybody explain it?

Comment: (For an effective line break append two blanks to a line you want a break after.)

Answer (score 2):

It is theta of $2^{2n}$:

$$2^{2n+2}=4\cdot 2^{2n}=\Theta(2^{2n})$$

Comment: So you say this equation is correct? But the question is wrong, right?